# If time is before 17.00 use 17.00 OR if time is after 17.00 use value in cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Headline says it all. I'm trying to calculate worktime in minutes. Ex: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GmGyi4kQf8I2qvEJjfG3OZvm_n_kBbsw_doTi9J0KCk/edit?usp=sharing

I have to state when meeting start and when it stops. Overtime is from 17.00 so:
If a meeting is starting at 16.00 and last till 21.00 it, result must be 4 hours = 240 minutes.
But if a meeting starts at 18.00 and last till 21.00, result must 3 hours = 180 minutes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I added some alternatives to H9:H11 (minutes as time) and H12:H14 (minutes as integers). The MROUND function was used to round off to the closest minute and avoid floating point errors like those in G10:G12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell G9 of the spreadsheet you shared, I entered this formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(B9:B33)*len(C9:C33)*(C9:C33>B9:B33);if(timevalue(B9:B33)<timevalue("17.00.00"); mod(C9:C33-time(17;0;0);1)*1440; mod(C9:C33-B9:B33;1)*1440);))
```

It will only output a result when there are values in col B and col C and when col C > col B. 
See if this helps ?

Comment: I will look into at once.

Comment: Seems to fail in B13. When time is 18.00 it still counts from 17.00.

Comment: I changed the formula. Can you check again ?

Comment: Just perfect! Only I don' understand the use of len and timevalue.

Comment: Glad to hear. The len() function is there to check if there is something in the cells of col B and col C (=check if they are not blank). For the function timevalue() see also here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en. Please accept my answer if the solution works for you. Cheers, JP